# Using a struct pointer as a @property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, ipad

I want to use a `struct` pointer as a `@property` but I'm not sure how should I free it.

This is what I have now:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) InfoStruct * info;
```

.m:

```
@synthesize info; 
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.info = (struct InfoStruct *) malloc(sizeof(struct InfoStruct));
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    free(info);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Could the code above cause any trouble? Is it correct? Seems to work fine, but I think I need a reassurance.

Comment: Is it an option for you to use 'regular' objects, or you're porting some code and have to stick with structures?

Comment: Something like that. I could use NSObjects, but it requires a little bit more effort. I prefer to do it like this for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you use instances of that class. For example:

```
SomeClass *obj = [SomeClass new];
// never assign an address to obj.info
[obj release];
```

will be okay.

However, since you’ve declared that property to be read-write, you need to take into account the ownership of the object pointed by that structure.

For example, in:

```
SomeClass *obj = [SomeClass new];
obj.info = someInfo;
[obj release];
```

the object you’ve allocated in `-init` doesn’t get freed (you’re leaking it), and the object pointed to by `someInfo` gets freed. You could change the property setter to something like:

```
- (void)setInfo:(InfoStruct *)newInfo {
    if (newInfo != info) {
        free(info); // free previous object
        info = newInfo;
    }
}
```

in which case an assignment will always free the previous object unless the value being assigned is the same as the previous value. This means that your class effectively owns the object whose address is being assigned to the property.

If you decide that the class shouldn’t be responsible for freeing objects other than the one created in `-init`, things get a tad more complicated. If `info` is assigned some address other than the address of the original `info` created in `-init`, the client code needs to free `obj.info` before assigning it a new value. For example:

```
SomeClass *obj = [SomeClass new];
free(obj.info);
obj.info = someInfo;
[obj release];
```

That’s problematic because you have code outside of the class deallocating memory used by an object of that class, which is quite intrusive. And, if the class isn’t responsible for freeing objects other than the one created in `-init`, you need to keep additional state indicating that so that `-dealloc` only frees `info` if `info` wasn’t changed after the object was initialised.

Also, as Jim noted, the correct method name is `dealloc`.

Comment: Wow, this must be the most complete answer I ever got on SO :). Thanks! I think I'll make it read-only then. This way it will respect the ownership rule(the user will never free() it because he never alloc it). Cool. Thanks again!

Comment: Would you approach work if for instance `InfoStruct` had a field which is a pointer to a string allocated in run-time (e.g. `unsigned char *str` pointing to some other place in mem)?

Comment: @del Not really. In this case I’d define a function that is aware of the innards of the structure type and call it instead.

Answer (score 5):

This should work just fine. `@property`'s marked `assign` can handle regular C datatypes, whether they're numeric primitives or pointers. The fact that you're pointing at a struct doesn't change that.

Just be careful with your memory, because it looks like your property is read-write and anyone assigning to your property may not realize that your object "owns" it (e.g. calls `free()` in `-dealloc`, and requires `free()`-ing the old value of the property if you assign a new value to it). Unless you have a reason to want this property to be read-write, you may want to mark it `readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

That method should be called `dealloc`, not `destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

We know nothing about your `InfoStruct`. If it contains only primitive types, then calling `free(info)` is enough.
However, if it has pointers to other types you allocate memory for using `malloc`, then `free(info)` will not release these objects and you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: It does contain several pointers but it's not `free(info)`'s responsibility to free the objects they point to.

Comment: Good, than your fine with `free(info)` :)